# Msal v2 interaction_in_progress on login in angular app

Tags: angular, msal.js

Getting an unusual issue when using MSAL auth in our app where we get msal interaction_in_progress only on first login, and goes away after refresh but comes back anytime a user logs out/in.

Here is a snippet of the logs:
[image: msal_error-with_logs]

here is a snippet of the logs on refresh:
[image: msal_logs_on_refresh]

Using latest @azure/msal-angular (as of posting 2.5.0).

We aren't calling acquireToken or handleRedirect directly anywhere in our app as we make use of the MsalInterceptor and the MsalRedirectComponent.

Here are relevant snippets:

app.module.ts providers:
`

```
  providers: [
    StyleManagerService,
    Title,
    FeatureFlagService,
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MsalGuardConfigFactory
    },

    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ClaimsInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MsalInterceptorConfigFactory
    },
    MsalService,
    MsalBroadcastService,
    MsalGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent]
```

`

app.module.ts factories referenced in providers:
`

```
export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: `${authConfig.AzureAd__FrontendId}`,
      authority: `${authConfig.AzureAd__Instance}/${authConfig.AzureAd__TenantId}`,
      redirectUri: "/auth",
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false
    },

    system: {
      loggerOptions: {
        loggerCallback,
        logLevel: LogLevel.Info,
        piiLoggingEnabled: false
      }
    }
  })
}

export function MsalGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    authRequest: {
      scopes: ['User.Read']
    }
  }
}

export function MsalInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  const myProtectedResourcesMap = new Map<string, Array<string | ProtectedResourceScopes>>();
  myProtectedResourceMap.set(`${getBaseUrl()}api/*`, [`api://${authConfig.AzureAd__ClientId}/API.Read`, `api://${authConfig.AzureAd__ClientId}/API.Write`]);

  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    protectedResourceMap: myProtectedResourcesMap
  }
}
```

`

msal guard setup:

```
  {
    path: "",
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: "full",
    data: { title: siteName },
    canActivate: [MsalGuard]
  },
...

  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: MsalRedirectComponent
  },
```

app.component.ts ngInit:

```
    this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
      .pipe(filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).subscribe(() => {
              let activeAccount: AccountInfo = this.msalService.instance.getActiveAccount();

        });
```

Any ideas why this interaction_in_progress might be occurring?

Tried upgrading to latest version of msal-angular,
Looked at similar posts but none of them were using MsalRedirectComponent, MsalInterceptor, or were outdated

Comment: Possibly related to https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/5146

Comment: Yeah that does look similar, thanks for sharing I’ll try some of the options they shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay turns out the issue was our app was making an api call during initialization before msal was finished which did not check for interaction in progress. I added the typical check for interaction in progress (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/events.md) and the error is now gone.